# How are [clip] and [crop] tags different?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently, we have [clip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clip) x700 and [crop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crop) x57. Their excerpts mostly overlap:

Clip:

> To limit or reduce the extent of one dataset by the extents or boundary of another.

Crop:

> In this context means to cut or trim an image or raster file. Do not use in association with questions to do with farming or agriculture.

Questions tagged with [clip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clip) and [crop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crop) seem to have the same scope.

Are they different or the same?

Comment: I would never use crop to describe a vector clip. I think crop is always on raster data and to a rectangle. I'm in two minds about whether the distinction I perceive warrants two tags so I'm keen to see any answers from others.

Comment: I agree with @Midavalo that clip is the more generic of the two so I'd be happy with crop as a synonym of clip.  In ArcGIS Clip_management clips rasters and Clip_analysis does vectors.

Comment: Please note that crop (raster sense) and crop (farm crops) are used in that small field of GIS too example http://www.agr.gc.ca/eng/?id=1343066456961

Comment: I've made [tag:crop] a synonym of [tag:clip].  For now I have not merged, pending a stronger vote. If no dissenting views emerge I'm happy to merge (and leave crop behind as a synonym), if you ping me later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comments, in GIS I think the term "crop" is a kind of subset of "clip" specific to rectangular trimming of image edges.  With this in mind I believe [clip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clip) should be used to cover both clip and crop - there is not enough difference between the two to keep separate tags.

That said, we do have questions regarding image classification attempting to classify land-use such as forestry, rivers, and agriculture.  Some of these also use the [crop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crop) tag, presumably for agriculture classification.  If we retag [crop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crop) to [clip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clip) we will need to also retag some of these to [agriculture](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agriculture).

I believe the tag [crop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crop) should then be synonymised to [clip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clip).

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick research in questions tagged [crop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crop) and 53 from 57 were about clipping/cropping either raster or vector data. Just like [clip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clip).

While in the GIS world (i.e., outside GIS SE) 'clip' and 'crop' can have distinct meanings (for example, the ones [commented by PolyGeo](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4857/how-are-clip-and-crop-tags-different#comment9112_4857)), within GIS SE tags can be (are) used in a more relaxed terms so to group questions per subject efficiently.

By doing this quick search on [crop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crop) I saw many potential duplicate questions to [clip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clip). Making one tag synonym of the other will help people finding and marking those accordingly. Therefore, I propose [clip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clip) to be the master because it has been spontaneously used more frequently.

About agricultural 'crops' (the other 4 questions among 57) I think they could be tagged [agriculture](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agriculture) and we would not have a tag with a competing name from a specific field (agriculture) to a common geoprocessing operation.